# How to fix my droid phone that is just blank

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, samsung-droid-charge

I have the Samsung droid Charge (SCH-I510) and I tried to load bootloader to it and now the screen is just black.when I insert usb to it,the buttons at the bottom light up but the screen is just blank.I there anyway to connect the phone to a pc so I can flash it I don't care about the files on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ODIN to reflash your phone. Its the last resort I can say for your phone. I was too in same situation. I was having Sammy's Galaxy S which on rooting and upgrading went blank. I used ODIN and refalsh it with stock rom and made my phone alive. Give it a try. See the link here it might help. There might be some problem with your network after recovering. 
See  [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1122657). Its for Verizon. Kindly find your appropriate ROM and flash it. XDA forum is great resource for Andy users/developers

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I personally know is to flash a custom recovery, and wipe your phone from there. If you can, follow [this tutorial](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/install-cwm-recovery-samsung-droid-charge-sch-i510-fp5-build-using-odin/) to install a custom recovery. Also, the tutorial doesn't mention it, but if you don't have windows, and have macOS or Linux, use JOdin. If you're using JOdin for macOS, install [this driver](https://bitbucket.org/benjamin_dobell/heimdall/downloads/Heimdall-1.4.1-Unofficial-Signed.dmg) before installing JOdin. If you need any help, feel free to comment on my answer, and I can help you .